# Heroku Push Fail: error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

Tags: django, git, heroku, deployment

I'm deploying a Django project on Heroku but this error constantly occurred during `git push heroku master`:

```
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I have searched other answers and it seems like it's the slow internet connection problem with huge codebase. So far I have tried:

#### 1. increase the buffer

`git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000`

#### 2. verified my Heroku account

#### 3. added my SSH key to Heroku app

But none of this worked. I still get no response at the `collect statics` stage and after a few hours the same error happened. Can someone tell me what's wrong with this? How can I fix this? Thanks a lot!

#### the full log

```
(venv) my@my-pc:~/Dropbox/CS/web/pro001$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 401, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (390/390), done.
Writing objects: 100% (401/401), 29.70 MiB | 1.57 MiB/s, done.
Total 401 (delta 170), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.7
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting dj-database-url==0.5.0 (from -r /tmp/build_21186e586e3e04ef5c7e4f57db313e07/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/a6/4b8578c1848690d0c307c7c0596af2077536c9ef2a04d42b00fabaa7e49d/dj_database_url-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting Django==2.1.4 (from -r /tmp/build_21186e586e3e04ef5c7e4f57db313e07/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/9a/0c028ea0fe4f5803dda1a7afabeed958d0c8b79b0fe762ffbf728db3b90d/Django-2.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (7.3MB)
remote:        Collecting django-heroku==0.3.1 (from -r /tmp/build_21186e586e3e04ef5c7e4f57db313e07/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/af/5475a876c5addd5a3494db47d9f7be93cc14d3a7603542b194572791b6c6/django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.9.0 (from -r /tmp/build_21186e586e3e04ef5c7e4f57db313e07/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/da/b8dd8deb741bff556db53902d4706774c8e1e67265f69528c14c003644e6/gunicorn-19.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112kB)
remote:        Collecting Pillow==5.4.1 (from -r /tmp/build_21186e586e3e04ef5c7e4f57db313e07/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/5e/e91792f198bbc5a0d7d3055ad552bc4062942d27eaf75c3e2783cf64eae5/Pillow-5.4.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.0MB)
remote:        Collecting psycopg2==2.7.6.1 (from -r /tmp/build_21186e586e3e04ef5c7e4f57db313e07/requirements.txt (line 6))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/2a/61a8f9719bd6df5b421abd91740cb0595fc3c17b28eaf89fe4f144472ca6/psycopg2-2.7.6.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.7MB)
remote:        Collecting pytz==2018.7 (from -r /tmp/build_21186e586e3e04ef5c7e4f57db313e07/requirements.txt (line 7))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/0e/2365ddc010afb3d79147f1dd544e5ee24bf4ece58ab99b16fbb465ce6dc0/pytz-2018.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (506kB)
remote:        Collecting whitenoise==4.1.2 (from -r /tmp/build_21186e586e3e04ef5c7e4f57db313e07/requirements.txt (line 8))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/2a/b51377ab9826f0551da19951257d2434f46329cd6cfdf9592ea9ca5f6034/whitenoise-4.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Installing collected packages: dj-database-url, pytz, Django, whitenoise, psycopg2, django-heroku, gunicorn, Pillow
remote:        Successfully installed Django-2.1.4 Pillow-5.4.1 dj-database-url-0.5.0 django-heroku-0.3.1 gunicorn-19.9.0 psycopg2-2.7.6.1 pytz-2018.7 whitenoise-4.1.2
remote: 
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the error myself. I stupidly added one `/` in the STATICFILES_DIRS after the static. Removing it makes deployment work fine.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"), # remove the `/` 
]
```